# Generating wrong Unix timestamp

Tags: c++, timestamp

I am trying to get the timestamp for some date, currently I'm using the function `mktime()` but it is generating the timestamp for the current date, not the one I put in the input. Here is the code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long unixTimeStamp(
    int year,
    int month,
    int day,
    int hour,
    int min,
    int sec
  ) {

  tm uts_time;
  uts_time.tm_year = year - 1900;
  uts_time.tm_mon = month - 1;
  uts_time.tm_mday = day;
  uts_time.tm_sec = sec;
  uts_time.tm_min = min;
  uts_time.tm_hour = hour;

  time_t out = mktime(&uts_time);

  return time(&out);
}

int main() {
  cout << unixTimeStamp(2010,8,29,1,22,9) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1362541046
```

Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `time` incorrectly.

See a [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/) for the `time` function. If the parameter is not `NULL`, it will set it to the current calendar time.

Remove the call to `time(&out)` and just return `out` as it is.

```
time_t unixTimeStamp(
    int year,
    int month,
    int day,
    int hour,
    int min,
    int sec
  ) 
{

  tm uts_time;
  uts_time.tm_year = year - 1900;
  uts_time.tm_mon = month - 1;
  uts_time.tm_mday = day;
  uts_time.tm_sec = sec;
  uts_time.tm_min = min;
  uts_time.tm_hour = hour;

  return mktime(&uts_time);
}

int main() {
  cout << unixTimeStamp(2010,8,29,1,22,9) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1283008929

Comment: Note that this will give you the timestamp for the requested time in **local time**. If you want it in GMT or UTC, you will need to fiddle with it a bit more.